# Check if string already exists in a field in cloudfirestore field and flutter

Tags: dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I have a collection called IDS in cloudfirestore, inside it, there is a document called IDs,inside this document I have fields starting with ID1 to reach almost ID14000,The user enters his id inside a textfield,I need to check if the id exists in the fields thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
final CollectionReference dbIDS = Firestore.instance.collection('IDS');

QuerySnapshot _query = await dbIDS
    .where('ID', isEqualTo: theUserInputID)
    .getDocuments();

if (_query.documents.length > 0) {
  // the ID exists
}
```

Comment: my field have different  names. Not  all  of them are ID,i have ID1 ,ID2,ID3,ID4.....will your code work if this is the case

Comment: just make 'ID' whatever the field name is then.  and change isEqualTo to be something that checks against whatever the values are.